# VS 2022 - 17.3.6 - Unused Using statements no longer greyed out even though in tools the option is checked out

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.3.6
I noticed recently that Unused Using statements are not greyed out. I am using DARK Theme, not the high contrast one.
Has anyone experienced the same issue?
[image]

Comment: Still unsolved in VS 17.5.4.

Comment: The same occurs for me using v17.5.5. Same setup as OP (dark theme, option is checked).

Comment: I have 2 machines with VS 17.6.3, one has the issue, the other does not ╮(￣▽￣")╭

Comment: I have this problem on VS 17.6.4, not only this but no graying out of any kind works anymore anywhere.

Comment: Is there an old ruleset file that configs these things in your solution? In that case, try removing the ruleset file, and re-open the solution to see if that affects the fade out of unused usings.
(It did in my solutions)